# Null exception when mocking Spring service in test

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, mocking, mockito

I am attempting to mock a Spring service and user the web MVC context to test a correct response JSON object is returned from the controller. It seems an exception is caught in the controller, but points to null, thus returning an unsuccessful response with no body.

I'm unsure what annotation I may be missing here. The service does require the SSRS config object in the constructor and upon debugging while testing, it is null in the controller try/catch block.

If that's the problem, I'm not sure how to fix it. If not, I'm unsure how to proceed to prevent the exception from being thrown.

```
@Slf4j
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/reports")
public class ReportsController {
    private final ReportsService reportsService;

    public ReportsController(@NonNull ReportsService reportsService) {
        this.reportsService = reportsService;
    }

    @PutMapping("/getReport")
    @Step
    public ApiResult getReport(@RequestBody ReportParamJSON params)
    {
        ApiResult result = new ApiResult();

        try {
            byte[] rptStream = reportsService.getReport(params.name, params.params, params.format);
            result.body = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(rptStream));
            result.success = true;
        }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            result.success = false;
            result.messages.add(exc.toString());
        }

        return result;
    }
}

@Slf4j
@Service
public class ReportsService {
private final SsrsConfig ssrsConfig;

    public ReportsService(@NonNull SsrsConfig ssrsConfig) {
        this.ssrsConfig = ssrsConfig;
    }

    @Step
    public byte[] getReport(String report, List<ReportParam> params, String format) throws Exception{
        // return some binary data.
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest
@WithMockUser
public class ReportsControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ReportsService reportsService;

    @Before
    public void initMocks(){
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void givenGetReportUri_whenRequestReport_thenReturnReport() throws Exception {

        String response = "{\"body\":\"data\",\"success\":true,\"messages\":[]}";

        ArrayList<ReportParam> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new ReportParam("number", "1000"));
        params.add(new ReportParam("status", "1"));
        when(reportsService.getReport("test", params, "PDF")).thenReturn("data".getBytes());


        mockMvc.perform(put("/api/reports/getReport")
            .content("{\n" +
                    "  \"format\": \"PDF\",\n" +
                    "  \"name\": \"test\",\n" +
                    "  \"params\": [\n" +
                    "    {\n" +
                    "      \"name\": \"number\",\n" +
                    "      \"value\": \"1000\"\n" +
                    "    },\n" +
                    "    {\n" +
                    "      \"name\": \"status\",\n" +
                    "      \"value\": \"1\"\n" +
                    "    }\n" +
                    "  ]\n" +
                    "}")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)).andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
            .andExpect(content().string(response));
    }
}

@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "ssrs")
@Component
@Data
public class SsrsConfig {
    private String endpointUri;
}
```

Comment: checkout my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605095/unit-testing-rest-services-with-spring-boot-and-junit/50605258#50605258 It is the same issue

Comment: My problem is not the same at all and is more complex than yours. I'm not even mocking the controller.

Comment: Let me guess the `ReportParam` doesn't have an `equals`  and `hashCode` method. Which makes the argument matching in Mockito fail which then resorts to default behavior of returning `null` for your method execution.